# Why golang/x/crypto/acme/autocert with DirCache throw permission denied?

Tags: docker, go

My goal is to share the cert in a docker volume. I create the docker volume with `$ docker volume create secret-dir`. So, I can stop and remove the container without worrying that `autocert` did ACME challenge every time I restart the container.

In the Dockerfile, I use `USER 10001:10001`, a non-root user.

I mounted the docker volume with `docker run ... -v secret-dir:/secret-dir`.

I make sure that USER `10001:10001` have access to the mounted volume by adding `mkdir /secret-dir && chown 10001:10001 /secret-dir && chmod 750 /secret-dir`.

I double check it and `ls -l` shows that the mounted folder is owned by USER `10001:10001` with folder permission of 0750, later I chmod it to `777`, but the same issue persist.

main.go

```
        m := &autocert.Manager{
            Cache:      autocert.DirCache("secret-dir"), // removing this will solve the issue but it will do ACME challenge every time I restart the container. `crt.sh` shows that I created new cert after I restarted the container.
            Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
            HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist(*host),
        }
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.19-alpine3.16 AS stage0

...

FROM alpine:3.16 AS stage1

WORKDIR /

RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates

RUN adduser \
    -h "/dev/null" \
    -g "" \
    -s "/sbin/nologin" \
    -D \
    -H \
    -u 10001 \
    playerone

RUN mkdir /secret-dir && chown 10001:10001 /secret-dir && chmod 777 /secret-dir

FROM scratch

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=stage0 /main /main

COPY --from=stage1 /secret-dir/ /secret-dir/
COPY --from=stage1 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

COPY --from=stage1 /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
USER 10001:10001

EXPOSE 80/tcp 443/tcp
```

The error:

```
2022/10/08 22:27:32 server.go:3230: http: TLS handshake error from **my external ip**:**my external port**: open secret-dir/acme_account+key2164117716: permission denied
2022/10/08 22:59:26 server.go:3230: http: TLS handshake error from ip**:**my external port**: acme/autocert: missing certificate
```